# Ubuntu 16.04LTS: Reset back to 14.04 LTS

Tags: lubuntu

Using Lubuntu-Desktop: Energy setting set to Shut-Down when computer being switched OFF. Instead I get the dialogue with several options?
When selecting "Suspend", the computer goes to sleep but cannot be woken up?
Owing to these and other problems with this Upgrade, how can I reset the System back to the 14.04 LTS Version, which performed perfectly???

Frustrated,
Ricky

Comment: Back up your data and do a clean install for 14.04.

Comment: Ok, but HOW? without wiping out my Windows-Operating System?

Comment: The same way you installed Ubuntu in the first place?

Comment: "The same way you installed Ubuntu in the first place?"

Comment: OK, I used a live Disc to originally install next to my Windows System (Dual-Boot). If I now use the same method, what happens> does this then overwrite the 16.04 LTS or does this occupy an additional space? AND will the Windows OS be also safe or wiped out? Please answer in Detail as I am unsure.